# How to determine if a dictionary has some key?

Tags: julia

I want to key into a dictionary, but Julia throws an exception if the key does not exist. To avoid the exception, I first have to check if they key exists in the dictionary.

I'm using this custom function for now:

```
function has_some_key(dict, key)
   for (k, v) in dict
       if k == key
           return true
       end
   end
   return false
end
```

Is there a better way to determine if a dictionary has a mapping for a given key?

Answer (score 6):

[`haskey`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.haskey) will check whether some collection has a mapping for a given key:

```
julia> d
Dict{Int64,String} with 2 entries:
  2 => "two"
  1 => "one"

julia> haskey(d, 1)
true

julia> haskey(d, 3)
false
```

Comment: you can also use `2 in keys(d)`

Answer (score 4):

Another way, which might be viable depending on your use case, is to use `get` to provide a default value in case the key is not present:

```
julia> d = Dict(1 => "one", 2 => "two")
Dict{Int64,String} with 2 entries:
  2 => "two"
  1 => "one"

julia> get(d, 1, "zero")
"one"

julia> get(d, 3, "zero")
"zero"
```

There's also `get!`, which will store the default value for the queried key as well.